# java , jpa cast exception

Tags: java, jpa, casting

it is my second time that i play with jpa,

i wrote this pice of code:

```
   String queryString = "SELECT e.uidprofile, e.profilecode, e.catUso, max(e.zonaClim), e.classePrev, e.beta1, e.beta2, e.beta3, e.beta4"
            + " FROM "
            +  entityClass.getSimpleName()
            + " e "
            + " WHERE e.catUso like :code "
            + " group by e.uidprofile, e.profilecode, e.catUso, e.classePrev, e.beta1, e.beta2, e.beta3, e.beta4"
            + " order by e.uidprofile";

    Query query = entityManager.createQuery(queryString);

    query.setParameter("code", "C" + "%");

    List<SamTbProfileMapping> resultList = query.getResultList();

    ClassLoader c1 = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
    ClassLoader c2 = resultList.getClass().getClassLoader();

    if(resultList.size()>0){
        System.out.println(resultList.get(0).getCatUso());
    }
```

Debugging it:

- `resultList` has all the fields of `SamTbProfileMapping` with the right values
- the count of the objects is right
- after the line `List<SamTbProfileMapping> resultList = query.getResultList();`
    i get `C2` to `null` and `System.out.println(resultList.get(0).getCatUso());` 
    says that resultList can not be Casted To `SamTbProfileMapping`

Comment: What does System.out.println(resultList.get(0).getClass().getSimpleName()); return?

Comment: Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to entity.SamTbProfileMapping

Comment: This time happens working with objects mysterious.

Comment: lol, you are tellin me the same thing of @DRCB ? :)

Comment: @frank You'd better reconsider your accepts and look at the other answers. If it's possible better let the framework to do casting for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are retrieving a list of arrays with your query. Not a list of objects.

`"Select a, b, c, d, from something"` - returns `List<Object[]>`

Then access separate members in the same order as in query.
For example:

```java
 List<Object[]> myList = query.getResultList();

 MyAClass a1 = (MyAClass) myList.get(0)[0];
 MyBClass b1 = (MyBClass) myList.get(0)[1];
```

To select an object list you can use:

`"select a from MyClass a where ..."`

Then

```java
 List<MyClass> myList = query.getResultList();
 MyClass result1 = myList.get(0);
```

Comment: Isn't that the case with `createNativeQuery` only? I remember wrestling with that in an effort of optimizing performance...

Comment: please can you tell me how do i retrive those a,b,c,d .. then ??

Comment: @frank iterate through the list, and fill in the fields of the object one by one. Then put ready object into a list... Just the same as the JPA implementation would do.

Comment: can you link me a pice of code ?? i don't get it ... sorry for the noobness

Comment: you mean like this ? List<Object[]> resultList = query.getResultList();   now i should iterate on that list ? but i can cast to things ??

Comment: This casting not actually true, the types are usual mapped from   result set mapping.

Comment: how do i know the resultset mapping ? i mean there is a way to retrive it from the resultList ? or i should look at table db?

Comment: If you can't know the type you can't cast the type because of `ClassCastException`

Comment: @frank I don't exactly understand what you ask. Result type is completely defined by your query. Additionally you can use reflection to check the result if a query is created dynamically.

Comment: That or they can use the SamTbProfileMapping constructor in the query, assuming it takes all the parameters in the query.  The query would then return SamTbProfileMapping objects instead of object[].  "select <packageName>.SamTbProfileMapping(e.uidprofile, e.profilecode, e.catUso, max(e.zonaClim),..) from .."

Comment: @Chris i should check it .. i will see ;)

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use the [typed version of the createQuery function](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#createQuery%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class%29) (available from 1.6)

Try:

```
Query query = entityManager.createQuery(queryString, SamTbProfileMapping.class);
```

Of course, this implies that `SamTbProfileMapping` has to be an entity class. And I'm not sure about the aggregate column, you might need to apply an alias to that.

Comment: Could you explain why single entry and how the results is mapped?